# Fourier series in the equation of the vibrating string

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, wave-equation, sturm-liouville

Consider the following problem for a vibrating string:

$$
u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}, \quad u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0, \quad u(x,0)=f(x), \quad u_t(x,0)=g(x) \tag{1}
$$

Applying the method of separation of variables and using the boundary conditions, we obtain that

$$
u_{n}(x, t)=\left[A_{n} \cos \left(\frac{n \pi c t}{L}\right)+B_{n} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi c t}{L}\right)\right] \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right) \tag{2}
$$

Applying now the first initial condition,

$$
u(x, 0)=f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\right) \tag{3}
$$

If $f(x)$ is a periodic function of period $L$, then its Fourier series expansion would be given by

$$
f\left(x\right)=\frac{a_{0}}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[a_{n} \cos \left(\frac{2n \pi x}{L}\right)+ b_{n} \sin \left(\frac{2n \pi x}{L}\right) \right] \tag{4}
$$

However, equations (3) and (4) do not coincide because of the $2$ factor within the sine of (4).

How could we relate expressions (3) and (4) to obtain the coefficients $A_n$? Should we assume that the period of $f(x)$ is $L/2$ instead of $L$?

Comment: You assume a period of 2L rather. Then your Fourier series has the form of (4) but without the 2-factor.

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk but then the expression for $b_n$ would be $b_{n}=\frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{2L} f(x) \sin \left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right) d x$, so the limits of the integral would be out of the domain $[0,L]$ of the problem

Comment: Choosing $f$ to be odd, you get $b_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^Lf(x)\sin(n\pi x/L)dx$ ?

Comment: You don't need to match $(3)$ and $(4)$ to get the coefficients $A_{n}$. You need to multiply both sides of $(3)$ by $\sin(m \pi x/L)$ and integrate over $x \in [0, L]$ as that is the domain of your problem i.e $$\int_{0}^{L} f(x) \sin \left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) dx = \sum A_{n} \int_{0}^{L} \sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \sin \left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) dx$$ A similar idea goes for the time derivative $u_{t}(x, 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you have to keep in mind is that a regular Sturm-Liouville problem gives you a complete orthogonal set of eigenfunctions. So the Fourier expansion of any function $f\in L^2[0,L]$ will converge in the $L^2$ sense to $f$.

For the case at hand, the solutions of
$$
               f''=\lambda f,\;\;\; f(0)=f(L)=0,
$$
are constant multiples of the following:
$$
            \sin\frac{n\pi x}{L},\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
These functions automatically form a complete orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,L]$. In particular, the following holds for all $g\in L^2[0,L]$:
$$
                 g=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\int_0^L g(x')\sin\frac{n\pi x'}{L}dx'}{\int_0^L\sin^2\frac{n\pi x'}{L}dx'}\right]\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}
$$
The expansion holds in the $L^2$ sense, but not necessarily at every point, because changing the values of $g$ on a set of measure $0$ does not change the Fourier series given above. You do not have to try to relate this series to any other Fourier expansion. It's guaranteed to converge in $L^2$ to the function $g$.